# Multi-Factorial and Series with Triple-factorial terms

Tags: special-functions

> Let $n!^{(k)}$ denote a multi-factorial which is defined by
>     $$
>     n!^{(k)} = \begin{cases}
>       1                     & n \leqslant 0, \\
>       n,                    & 0 < n < k,\\
>       n\times(n-k)!^{(k)},  & n \geqslant k.
>     \end{cases}
>   $$
>
> *E.g.* $8!^{(3)}=8\times5!^{(3)}=8\times5\times2!^{(3)}=8\times5\times2=80$. For $k=3$ we may also put down $8!!!$.

For the case of $k=1$, *Mathematica* has `Factorial[]` or `!` at hand.

For the case of $k=2$, there is `Factorial2[]` or `!!` which calculates double factorials.

For the general case of a $k$<sup>th</sup> factorial, I could define by recursion

```
In[1]:= MultiFactorial[n_, k_] := If[n < k, If[n <= 0, 1, n], n MultiFactorial[n - k, k]]
```

which correctly outputs $8!^{(3)}$ as

```
In[2]:= MultiFactorial[8, 3]
Out[2]:= 80
```

But when I have a multi-factorial in every term of an infinite series, *Mathematica* spits out the original input:

```
In[3]:= Sum[((-1)^n MultiFactorial[3 n, 3])/MultiFactorial[3 n + 1, 3], {n, 0, +∞}]
Out[3]:= (* More or less the same *)
```

[***Edit***]

Definition by `Product[]`

```
In[4]:= MultiFactorial[n_, k_] := Product[i, {i, n, 1, -k}]
In[5]:= Sum[((-1)^n MultiFactorial[3 n, 3])/MultiFactorial[3 n + 1, 3], {n, 0, +∞}]
```

suggests that the sum is divergent.

Yep, I'm trying to verify if

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (3n)!^{(3)}}{(3n+1)!^{(3)}} = -\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{4} \ln\left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{2}}{6}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1+2\sqrt[3]{2}}.$$

**Question**: Are there any built-in functions for the cases of $k\geqslant3$ which is OK to sum?

Comment: You might be interested in a nonrecursive definition: `MultiFactorial[n_, k_] := With[{q = Quotient[n - 1, k]}, k^(q + 1) Gamma[n/k + 1]/Gamma[n/k - q]]`

Comment: It worked. Output `N[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 4/3, -1]]` which is $0.590718\cdots$, the same as the given result. Why the difference? `Prod` doesn't seem to be non-recursive? And I'm now trying to comprehending yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(too long for a comment)

Sasha has given an expression in terms of falling factorials. For some reason, however, `Sum[(-1)^j MultiFactorial[3 j, 3]/MultiFactorial[3 j + 1, 3], {j, 0, Infinity}]` remains unsimplified using the definition of the multifactorial in terms of `FactorialPower[]`.

Either of the following definitions work, though:

```
MultiFactorial[n_, k_] :=
      With[{q = Quotient[n - 1, k]}, k^(q + 1) Gamma[n/k + 1]/Gamma[n/k - q]]

MultiFactorial[n_, k_] := With[{q = Quotient[n + k - 1, k]}, k^q q! Binomial[n/k, q]]
```

where `Sum[(-1)^j MultiFactorial[3 j, 3]/MultiFactorial[3 j + 1, 3], {j, 0, Infinity}]` now evaluates to `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 4/3, -1]`. Applying `FunctionExpand[]` to this yields a rather complex expression, but at least it involves only elementary functions.

Unfortunately,

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[
              Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 4/3, -1] ==
              -2^(-5/3) Log[2^(1/3) - 1] + Sqrt[3] 2^(1/3) ArcTan[Sqrt[3]/(1 + 2^(4/3))]/6]]
```

takes quite long to evaluate, and does not yield anything useful. Thus, we need to exploit a few special function identities like the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1), yielding the identity

$${}_2 F_1\left({{1,1}\atop{\frac43}}\mid-1\right)=\frac12{}_2 F_1\left({{\frac13,1}\atop{\frac43}}\mid\frac12\right)$$

which happens to have [a convenient representation in terms of elementary functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/08/13/02/0008/).

Using that identity, we have

```
With[{z = 1/2}, (-Log[1 - z^(1/3)] - (-1)^(2/3) Log[1 + (-1)^(1/3) z^(1/3)] +
     (-1)^(1/3) Log[1 - (-1)^(2/3) z^(1/3)])/(3 z^(1/3))]/2 ==
-2^(-5/3) Log[2^(1/3) - 1] + Sqrt[3] 2^(1/3) ArcTan[Sqrt[3]/(1 + 2^(4/3))]/6 // FullSimplify
```

which quickly evaluates to `True`.

My point here, now, is that although *Mathematica* knows a fair bit about special functions, sometimes one could benefit a lot from helping *Mathematica* a little bit with a few identities...

Comment: +1. If you follow the strategy outlined in my answer of first simplifying the coefficients, there won't be any problem: `a[j_] := Evaluate [
  FullSimplify[MultiFactorial[3 j, 3]/MultiFactorial[3 j + 1, 3], 
   Assumptions -> j \[Element] Integers]]` re-expresses the sum in terms of Gamma functions and you're all set.

Comment: @whuber, the `FullSimplify[]` produces the result `Gamma[4/3] Gamma[1 + j]/Gamma[4/3 + j]` which is more enlighteningly expressed as `j!/Pochhammer[4/3, j]`. With this expression, the expression in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function quickly drops out: $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j!}{(4/3)_j}(-1)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_j}{(4/3)_j}(-1)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_j (1)_j}{(4/3)_j}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}={}_2 F_1\left({{1,1}\atop{4/3}}\mid -1\right)$$

Comment: This answers my original intent, and provided a way to verify that the two results are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

The multifactorial you are building is built-in in *Mathematica* under the disguise of `FactorialPower`:

```
MultiFactorial2[n_, k_] := FactorialPower[n, Quotient[n - 1, k] + 1, k]
```

which is the equivalent to J. M.'s expression.

Comment: Using this definition in the sum does not give something that can be symbolically evaluated, unfortunately (the result still has `FactorialPower[]` expressions within the `Sum[]`). Thankfully, `FactorialPower[]` and `Binomial[]` have a simple relationship, and `Binomial[]` can be handled by `Sum[]`. See my answer.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this definition, but the sum still doesn't evaluate.

Answer (score 5):

***Mathematica*** actually can perform the sum as originally specified.  First, supply the recursive definition of "multi-factorial":

```
factorial[n_, k_] /; n <= 0 := 1;
factorial[n_, k_] /; n <= k := n;
factorial[n_, k_] := factorial[n, k] = n factorial[n - k, k];
```

The strategy is to simplify the coefficients that will appear in the sum.  Unfortunately, a direct attack won't work:

```
a[n_] := Evaluate[Simplify[factorial[3 n, 3] / factorial[3 n + 1, 3], 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0]]
```

This doesn't get us anywhere.  Instead, let's try...guessing:

```
a = FindSequenceFunction[Table[factorial[3 n, 3] / factorial[3 n + 1, 3], {n, 1, 10}]]
```

> $\frac{\text{Pochhammer}[1,\text{$\#$1}]}{\text{Pochhammer}\left[\frac{4}{3},\text{$\#$1}\right]}\&$

We are home free.  We can even do a more general sum, using a variable `x` instead of $-1$:

```
f[x_] := Evaluate[Sum[x^n a[n], {n, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify]
```

The answer:

```
f[-1]
```

> $\text{Hypergeometric2F1}\left[1,1,\frac{4}{3},-1\right]$

(Its connection with ArcTan and Log becomes apparent after looking at `FunctionExpand[f[x]]`.)

---

One should be sceptical of the result of `FindSequenceFunction`--it is only guaranteed to agree with the sequence of values given to it, not with all possible indexes--so let's find a way to confirm the correctness of this result.  All we have to go on is the recursive definition of `factorial`.  Somehow we need to relate `a` to this recursion.  Looking at `a` shows it relates `factorial[3n,3]` to `factorial[3n+1,3]`, whereas the recursive definition of `factorial` relates `factorial[3n,3]` to `factorial[3n+3,3]`.  We can get there in three steps, but first need to work out the next two:

```
b = FindSequenceFunction[Table[factorial[3 n - 1, 3]/factorial[3 n, 3], {n, 1, 10}]]
c = FindSequenceFunction[Table[factorial[3 n - 2, 3]/factorial[3 n - 1, 3], {n, 1, 10}]]
```

Now `1/(a[n-1]b[n]c[n])` ought to give us the ratio `factorial[3n]/factorial[3(n-1)]`, which, according to the recursion, had better equal $3n$.  Indeed,

```
1/(a[n - 1] b[n] c[n]) // FullSimplify
```

> $3n$

Because the first four values of `factorial` are $(1,1,2,3)$, we only need to verify that `a[0]`, `c[1]`, and `b[1]` return the first three successive ratios $1/1$, $1/2$, $2/3$, which indeed they do.  By induction, this *proves* the result of `FindSequenceFunction` is correct.

Comment: Replacing $3$ by $k$ gives the solution $_2F_1\left[1,1,1+\frac{1}{k},x\right]$.  Applying `FunctionExpand` for the case $k=3$ and simplifying yields $-\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \text{ArcTan}\left[1-\frac{x^{1/3}}{2 (1-x)^{1/3}},-\frac{\sqrt{3} x^{1/3}}{2 (1-x)^{1/3}}\right]-2 \text{Log}\left[1+\frac{x^{1/3}}{(1-x)^{1/3}}\right]+\text{Log}\left[1+\frac{x^{2/3}-(-(-1+x) x)^{1/3}}{(1-x)^{2/3}}\right]}{6 (1-x)^{2/3} x^{1/3}}$, showing the connection with `ArcTan` and `Log`.

Comment: You have `fact[]` in the definition of `a[]`... typo? Also, replacing `fact[]` with your definition of `factorial[]` in `a[]`'s definition yields the expected `$RecursionLimit` error...

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for looking at this! I made a really stupid mistake by using the wrong definition for `a`.  This requires a different approach, which I have incorporated in an edited version.  The new approach is a little weaker because it's not fully automatic and elementary, but it may still be of interest in showing how to discover useful formulas for recursively defined functions and how to prove them correct once they have been found.

Comment: (+1) I like to explore, and I like your answer. I hope you won't mind that I "accept" @J.M. 's answer, as his directly answers my question.